# Python Bucket Script - Help on editing

Tags: python, pandas

I need to edit the below script to perform a action, but as i'm new to Python im struggling.

The below script classifies words within a data set:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'men': ['men', 'boy'], 'women': ['women', 'girl', 'lady']}

def classify(text):
    gender = 'None of any'
    for i in d:
        if any(j in text for j in d[i]):
            gender = i
    return gender

df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['this is a boy', 'a girl', 'two women', 'cat']})
df['cat'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: classify(x))
print(df)
```

From my understanding, (please correct me if I'm wrong), the "pd.DataFrame" is "inline" with the script. I need the "pd.DataFrame" to pull from a CSV, running through the data and classifying, rather than it being "inline".

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need help with your logic or are you trying to understand how to read from a csv? If it is the latter - you can use `df=pd.read_csv("csv_filename.csv", ...)`. You can learn more in the docs here - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your csv file is named `data.csv`.

And it looks like this:

[image]

You can simply replace the line that contains `pd.DataFrame(...)` as `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')`.

Here's the final result:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'men': ['men', 'boy'], 'women': ['women', 'girl', 'lady']}

def classify(text):
    gender = 'None of any'
    for i in d:
        if any(j in text for j in d[i]):
            gender = i
    return gender

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')  # I changed this line
df['cat'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: classify(x))
print(df)
```

Comment: Hi Brian, the above script didn't work for me. I'm guessing, (as i say I'm new to this), the "df[text]" isn't present, its been replaced with "df = pd.read_csv". Do I need to name the data frame, so Python knows what to run "def classify" against? Cheers

Comment: Can you paste the error message you get from the script? It helps me understand what went wrong on your machine.

Comment: What do you see when you run `print(df['text'])`?

Comment: Do you have `text` appear at the top row in the *.csv file?

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, (i've added a images as its not letting me add code), sorry bit of a nube at this

Comment: What is the error message? Can you paste it in the comment?

Comment: KeyError: 'text'

Comment: It seems like that you do not have `text` at the top row in the csv file.

Comment: What does your csv file look like?

Comment: I dont have "text" appear at the top of the csv file, would this be needed to run?

Comment: Yes, the top row would be treated as the column name by pandas.

Comment: Brian, thanks for your help with this, I've got it working!! (This has been bugging me for so long!). I didn't know that you could highlight columns within a df using "[ ]", hence why I couldn't select the data to run the script against. I'm just sating with python so its good to start solving problem with scripting

Answer (score 0):

First create `DataFrame` by [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df  = pd.read_csv(file)
```

Then use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
for k, v in d.items():
    df.loc[df['text'].str.contains('|'.join(v)), 'cat'] = k
df['cat'] = df['cat'].fillna('None of any')
```

Word boundaries alternative:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    df.loc[df['text'].str.contains('|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in v)), 'cat'] = k

df['cat'] = df['cat'].fillna('None of any')
```

Or:

```
d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in d1)

df['cat'] = df['text'].str.extract(f'({pat})', expand=False).map(d1).fillna('None of any')


print(df)
            text          cat
0  this is a boy          men
1         a girl        women
2      two women        women
3            cat  None of any
```